# Need to show page header and an image side by side

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to learn React js and building my first app. I am new to frontend development. I want the header of my page just as StackOverflow website where just to the left of 'stack overflow', we have an image (At the top left corner of this page)(another example is youtube where we have a play button just to the left of the text 'youtube').

I have created a Header.js as below

```
import React from 'react'
import './Home.css'
import logo from '../images/company-logo.svg';

const Header = () => {

  return (    <div className="header">
    <img src={logo} />
    <h1>My App</h1>

  </div>)

}
export default Header
```

Below is my App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './Header'

const App = () => {

  return (
      <div>
        <Header />
      </div>
    )
  }

export default App
```

Below is Home.css

```
.header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #8d59c0;;
  padding: 30px 27px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

I am able to see the image and the header 'My App' but they are vertical as in the image on top and then below (let's say another row) I see the header. I need the side by side just like the StackOverflow logo on the top left.

Can you please guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`img` and `h1` together will render as block elements. You can make the wrapping div a flex row container and center align the image icon and header tags.

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[image]

[image: Edit need-to-show-page-header-and-an-image-side-by-side]